# Grouping columns format

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-tablix

I have a doubt of ssrs reporting service. I am trying to do a report in this format:

[image]

But I don't know how I have to group it. I have grouped by `merchant` and `event_date` but the output is this:

[image]

[image]

Please if someone could help me I would appreciate too much.

Comment: Why do you have two different groups of Merchant A? Is it due to them start at :30 minutes after the hour? If so you'd need to group by the Minute as well =FORMAT(Fields!Event_Time.Value, "mm").

Comment: As Hannover Fist asked, what is the logic that creates the 2nd group for merchant A? You said you grouped by by event_date but all records have the same date so the sample data might be incorrect?

Comment: @HannoverFist The first picture is of an old report that i have to replicate but i don´t know how to group it to get it in that format. The Merchant A is repeated two times because i think the report priorize the event_time sort.@AlanSchofield yes i only put one day for the example

Comment: I think this will be quite tricky to do in SSRS but if I was you, before I started, I would question if the report makes sense. If you had lots of 'events' across lots of merchants you would end up with the same merchant scattered across the report. I don't see how this can be useful. Typically, the output you already have is what most people would want in my opinion.

Comment: I would present the report to the users as you have it now and show the idfference and ask if they want it to be like the old way. If so ask them what differentiates the two groups of Merchant A.